# Changing route in browser MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, routes, controllers

I have a small issue and I will be glad if someone could help me.

I am creating a project from University and in the Menu I have reference to another website. I am using method `Redirect` in Home controller like this:

```
    public ActionResult MyReference()
    {
        ViewBag.Current = "MyReference";
        return Redirect("linktootherwebsite.com");
    }
```

It's working fine but when I put my mouse on the reference(Hover) I got path from old view which I deleted, I mean:

I got:

```
Home/MyReference
```

but I want

```
Home/linktootherwebsite.com
```

Or even:

```
linktootherwebsite.com
```

Thanks for all help.
Best wishes. :)

Comment: My redirection working fine, My issue is about path when I hover on action in my menu.

Comment: Why are you not using direct HTML anchor links, Instead of actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just add this to your RouteConfig.cs **before** the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "whatever",
    url: "Home/linktootherwebsite.com",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "MyReference",
    }
);
```

Comment: Another question would be why do you use a controller action in this case at all... the viewbag wont talk to the other website, just use the link as it is ... <a href=.......